# Installing FileZilla3 on Debian10 without internet

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, filezilla

I am facing this problem where there is an error while I try to install filezilla3. So as I wanted to install it offline, I used sftp to transfer FileZilla3 zip file from another computer that has internet, I have successfully unzip the file but when I tried to run there is this error.

vncuser2@osboxes:~$ ls
Desktop                                      Pictures
Documents                                    Public
Downloads                                    Templates
FileZilla3                                   Videos
FileZilla_3.47.2.1_x86_64-linux-gnu.tar.bz2  VNC-Server-6.7.1-Linux-x64.deb
Music

vncuser2@osboxes:~$ cd FileZilla3

vncuser2@osboxes:~/FileZilla3$ ls
bin  lib  share

vncuser2@osboxes:~/FileZilla3$ cd bin

vncuser2@osboxes:~/FileZilla3/bin$ ls
filezilla  fzputtygen  fzsftp  fzstorj

vncuser2@osboxes:~/FileZilla3/bin$ ./filezilla
./filezilla: error while loading shared libraries: libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Or is there a better way for me to install filezilla, please, help me out thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to download the packages on another PC - and make sure to check sure you have the packages you need. `apt depends` will tell you what you need

```
geek@test-box:/var/crash$ apt depends filezilla
filezilla
  Depends: filezilla-common (= 3.39.0-2)
  Depends: libc6 (>= 2.28)
  Depends: libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14)
  Depends: libfilezilla0 (>= 0.15.1)
  Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:3.0)
  Depends: libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.12.0)
  Depends: libgnutls30 (>= 3.6.5)
  Depends: libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.10.0)
  Depends: libnettle6
  Depends: libpugixml1v5 (>= 1.7)
  Depends: libsqlite3-0 (>= 3.5.9)
  Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2)
  Depends: libwxbase3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg)
  Depends: libwxgtk3.0-0v5 (>= 3.0.4+dfsg)
```

I'm lazy so I'd run `apt install -s filezilla` and grab the list of files from there.

[apt has a download only option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/408346/how-to-download-package-not-install-it-with-apt-get-command) - you can download the debs for these packages with

`apt download filezilla-common libfilezilla0 libgail-common libgail18 libgtk2.0-0 libgtk2.0-bin libgtk2.0-common libpugixml1v5 libwxbase3.0-0v5` downloads all these to the current directory.

You can copy these over, and if a file is missing, you can install the relevant package with dpkg.